# How to create a single event handler for a variety of events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I want to do the following with JavaScript/jQuery:

**JavaScript**

*Pseudo code!*

```
$.bindalleventhandler('[action]', eventHandler);

eventHandler = function(trigger, element){
    if(trigger == 2 && $(element).attr('event') == 'change'){
        // execute action when change occurs
    }
    else if(trigger == 5 && $(element).attr('event') == 'keydown'){
        // execute action on keydown event
    }
    else{
        //default click
        // execute action by click
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button action="action">click me</button>
<select name="name" action="action" event="change">
     <option value="value">name</option>
     <option value="value">name</option>
     <option value="value">name</option>
</select>
```

Someone knows where to start? It has to be AJAX proof just like the jQuery `$.on()` method.

I only want this for a variety of events and bind it to elements containing the action attribute. Maybe I just parse the HTML and then dynamically create event handlers but then I have to parse every AJAX call.

Disclaimer: I am not asking you to make code for me but to send me in the right direction.

Comment: Not a good idea, this information does not belong in the HTML at all. You could as well go back to using inline event handlers :D.

Comment: How do you mean I can use whatever attributes I like so long as my js is supported the browser should not have a problem with it. XHTML dude!

Comment: I don't understand your comment and how XHTML comes into the picture. You can store whatever you want in your HTML (using `data-` attributes, I must note), I wanted to point out whether it is a good idea or not. Your idea is not really different from inline event handlers (like `onclick`), it kills separation of concerns.

Comment: I want to attach an action which dynamically calls an ajax request. I do not want to use javascript inline I want it to be 100% html. Its xhtml because it does not follow the standards of plain html.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding on what XHTML is. Actually HTML5 is much more forgiving than XHTML, which has quite strict standards, because it needs to be XML-compliant. Whatever.

Comment: So far I knew html became xhtml when it has tags or attributes which are not supported by the browser. After reading http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp I must conclude you are right I was wrong :(

Comment: Don't rely on w3schools it is a bad resource. I suggest MDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you the general idea of how my custom-built `addEvent` function works:

```
function addEvent(element,event,callback) {
  if( !element.nodeName && element.length) {
    [].forEach.call(element,function(e) {addEvent(e,event,callback);});
  }
  else if( event instanceof Array) {
    event.forEach(function(e) {addEvent(element,e,callback);});
  }
  else if( callback instanceof Array) {
    callback.forEach(function(e) {addEvent(element,event,e);});
  }
  else {
    // do the actual event attaching here
  }
}
```

Basically, this allows me to pass something simple like
`addEvent(document.body,"click",function() {alert('Hi!');});`

Or I can do something more complicated, like:

```
addEvent(
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=date]"),
  ["focus","change","keyup"],
  function(e) {
    console.log(e.type+" event fired on "+e.target);
  }
);
```

You should be able to adapt my approach to your needs :)

Comment: +1 a much better solution than what the OP suggested.

Comment: Edited - forgot the `else` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You might be more interested in event delegation. The `$.on` method in jQuery is definitely a good choice here.

```
$(document.documentElement).on("click change focusin focusout submit keypress", "[action]", null, function(event) {
    if (event.type === this.getAttribute("event")) {
        var action = this.getAttribute("action");
        var $actionElement = $(this);

        // do something based on the action variable
    }
});
```

I've also written an event delegation library that works without jQuery (or with it) that uses the same basic philosophy that you are after:

**[DOM Event Delegator](https://github.com/gburghardt/dom_event_delegator)** (GitHub)

It is an object oriented approach to event delegation that allows you to write code like the example below:

**The JavaScript "controller"**

```
function BlogPostController() {}

BlogPostController.prototype = {

    actions: {
        change: [
            "markDirty"
        ],
        click: [
            "cancel"
        ],
        submit: [
            "save"
        ]
    },

    delegator: null,

    dirty: false,

    element: null,

    constructor: BlogPostController,

    init: function(element) {
        this.element = typeof element === "string" ? document.getElementById(element) ? element;
        this.delegator = new dom.events.Delegator(this, this.element).init();
        this.delegator.setEventActionMapping(this.actions);
    },

    destructor: function() {
        if (this.delegator) {
            this.delegator.destructor();
            this.delegator = null;
        }

        if (this.element) {
            this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);
            this.element = null;
        }
    },

    cancel: function(event, element, params) {
        event.stop();

        if (!this.dirty || confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel?")) {
            this.destructor();
        }
    },

    markDirty: function(event, element, params) {
        this.dirty = true;
        // "event.target" is the form field that just changed its value
    },

    save: function(event, element, params) {
        event.stop();

        // Extract info from the form and make an Ajax request
        // "event" is the event object
        // "event.target" is the <form> tag
        // "element" is the element with the "data-action" attribute (the <div id="blog_post_form"> tag)
        // "params" is arbitrary data passed along in the action, taken from the "data-actionparams" attribute on "element"

        alert(params.blog_post.id); // alerts 123

        this.dirty = false;
    }
};
```

**The HTML**

```
<div data-action="save" data-actionparams='{"blog_post":{"id":123}}' id="blog_post_form">
    <form data-action="markDirty" action="/blog_posts/123" method="post">
        <p>
            Title: <input type="text" name="title">
        </p>
        <p>
            Body:<br>
            <textarea name="body"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" data-action="cancel">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript to initialize the controller and make it usable**

```
var blogPost = new BlogPostController();
blogPost.init("blog_post_form");
```

By using the `data-action` attribute, you get a true separation of markup, style and behavior. No more binding event handlers to class names or tag names. You are free to refactor your markup without affecting your behavior.

Too often I've changed a class name on a button and had JavaScript functionality break. You won't get that with this approach.

Plus the DOM Event Delegator works seamlessly with jQuery and other libraries. There is an adaptor for the most popular frameworks so you can use jQuery under the hood to attach and detach event handlers.

Comment: I'm also building a framework called [Foundy](https://github.com/gburghardt/foundry) which utilizes the DOM Event Delegator, but also allows you to remove boiler plate code in JavaScript when instantiating controllers. You should check it out.